# EnableTransactionManagement for multiple databases in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I have an application that needs to access two databases. I am trying to use Spring transactions to accomplish this.

1) Since I have two databases and a transaction manager takes a datasource as a parameter, must I configure two transaction managers, with each @Transactional specifying the correct transaction manager to use? ex: @Transcational("database1"), @Transactional("database2").

2) Since @EnableTransactionManagement will look for a single transaction manager to use for all transactions, I do not think I can use this annotation. Is that the case? Can I still utilize transactions with @Transactional("database") and no @EnableTransactionManagement?

Answer (score 1):

Please look to the relevant documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional

Comment: The documentation does not state whether you should use @EnableTransactionManagement with multiple transaction managers.

Comment: @EnableTransactionManagement  annotation only say spring that methods annotated with Transactional must be wrapped by a Transaction manager. It doesn't for a single transaction manager. If you use single transnational resource, you're OK, no need to define transaction manager name. But if you have multiple, you need to tell spring which Transaction Manager it should use on the Transactional annotation itself.